# Select an element after inserting into DOM with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I inserted a `canvas` element into the DOM of a new file with the following code:

```
$('#nav_steps').html(canvas);
```

I want to select this canvas to do something with it, but I can't. Can you help me? Thanks.

```js
data.forEach(function(data) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = w_notepad;
        canvas.height = h_notepad;
        $(canvas).toggle(!data.isActive).appendTo('#canvas_panel');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w_notepad, h_notepad);
    };
    img.src = data.dataImageURL;
});
```

i want :

```
$("canvas:eq(0)");
```

Thank.

Comment: `$('#nav_steps').html(canvas).find("canvas")` ?

Comment: Where do you define canvas? Is it an HTML string?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i inserted to new file, and i want reuse it with new selected.
Thank

Comment: @Stryner it a new element var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

Comment: Have you tried to add an id or class name to the canvas element so you can later select it?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Do you have any specific problems with it, or errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no error, because i can't select the canvas has been add to new file in new file.
Thank

Comment: @OMGTran If you created the element yourself, you can simply save the variable and wrap it with jQuery: `var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), $canvas = $(canvas);` Then you just use `$canvas` like any other jQuery object (e.g. `var x = $canvas.width();`).

Comment: @user162097 OK thank you, i will try it.